# Memory Error during frame animation in Android application

Tags: android, memory, animation, memory-leaks

Hi im trying to set up a frame animation with a series of images as a background for my splash page in an android application at the moment there is no errors but when I run the application it quits unexpectedly. The first error which follows 10 garbage collections is E/dalvikvm-heap(276): 1234272-byte external allocation too large for this process. I have 17 images I am using for the frame animation each of them are 50k or less so I dont think that the image sizes can be the issue.

The java code I have implemented in my main activity is as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView frameanimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame_animation);
        AnimationDrawable frame_animation = (AnimationDrawable) frameanimation.getBackground();

        frame_animation.setVisible(true, true);
        frame_animation.start();
    }
```

I then have this code implementing an image view within my XML Layout file:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frame_animation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_animation"
android:background="@drawable/frame_animation"/>
```

and finally I have my animation drawable saved as 'frame_animation.xml' within my drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda5" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda6" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda7" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda8" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda9" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda10" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda11" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda12" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda13" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda14" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda15" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda16" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/homebckgrnda17" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

The full LogCat log that I get when running the application is shown here:

```
04-16 13:51:33.703: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 906 objects / 64688 bytes in 69ms
04-16 13:51:33.983: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 208 objects / 9952 bytes in 66ms
04-16 13:51:34.203: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54 objects / 2112 bytes in 51ms
04-16 13:51:34.443: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 13 objects / 536 bytes in 52ms
04-16 13:51:34.683: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 13 objects / 512 bytes in 54ms
04-16 13:51:35.133: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 20 objects / 824 bytes in 52ms
04-16 13:51:35.593: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 26 objects / 1216 bytes in 70ms
04-16 13:51:36.023: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 24 objects / 1008 bytes in 51ms
04-16 13:51:36.394: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 26 objects / 1128 bytes in 55ms
04-16 13:51:36.803: D/dalvikvm(276): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 24 objects / 984 bytes in 50ms
04-16 13:51:37.143: E/dalvikvm-heap(276): 1234272-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-16 13:51:37.143: E/GraphicsJNI(276): VM won't let us allocate 1234272 bytes
04-16 13:51:37.153: D/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
04-16 13:51:37.153: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.BadmintonTrain/com.android.BadmintonTrain.BadmintonTrainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.BadmintonTrain.BadmintonTrainActivity.onCreate(BadmintonTrainActivity.java:21)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 22 more
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:265)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
04-16 13:51:37.203: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
```

Any help is much appreciated, I just cannot figure out what is causing the problem.

Thanks

Comment: How big are the images? The size on disk usually differs greatly from the real size in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images you are using might be too large for an animation. How large are they? In an animation, Android loads all of the images into memory and uncompresses them meaning that every pixel will take 4 bytes. So 50k would mean that your image is 111px x 111px. It seems from the error each frame is about 480 x 640, which is really large. Try using smaller images.

Comment: Each of the images I have used is aparently 416 X 659, what kind of size images should I use? I am trying to fill the background with the image.

Comment: I reduced the file size of each of the images to approx 180 x 280 and it runs fine now thanks.